# Examples of machine code using fuzzy logic (all values in (0,1) interval and the extended set of discrete logical operators)

Tags: machine-code, fuzzy-logic

I'm interested in knowing how machine code would look using a discrete system, and what progress has been made in building systems based upon this concept.

In other words, where instead of dealing simply with 0/1 values, and the "and/or/not" primitives, one is using any values on (0,1) interval, and the extended set of operators that would accompany such computation (min, max, product, average, modular difference, mod 1 sum, etc).

I've tried endless searches on google and on here but found nothing at all to that explicitly relates to this seemingly fundamental idea.

Comment: I mean, in the non-analog world there isn't a concept of something that isn't binary. So what you describe would essentially just be vectorized operations in floating point numbers. In the analgog space, you can absolutely create constructs that produce the desired mathematical operations on the raw signals (and indeed, when Fuzzy Logic was invented, this us how it was done). So I guess I'm not really sure what you are expecting to find.

Comment: I guess my question is based on the idea of a fluid discrete computing system replacing the current system that is based upon isolated 0/1 transistors and boolean logic gates. As I wasnt able to find out anything on how feasible or far off such technology is from implementation or what exists on this concept, Im not sure if my question is too theoretical. But, yes, I am very interested in knowing how a programming system would evolve freed from its binary>ascii restraints. Any material at all would be helpful.

Comment: I mean, you're describing an analog system (by definition, digital is binary). They were quite extensively researched in the early days of computing. It just turns out that it's generally a LOT easier/cheaper to simply make a digital system fast enough to make up the bandwidth difference. Just like how serial busses have replaced parallel ones in just about every external peripheral interconnect. Noise concerns are a big deal with analog systems, and start to severely limit its practicality as well.